# SQL Uniqe xN Constraint

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

I want to create a table where a given column value can only occur N times. For example, in the schema below I would only want each `Foo` to be able to have 3 entries in `Bar`.

```
CREATE TABLE Bar(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  foo INT REFERENCES Foo(id)
);
```

I am using PostgreSQL which doesn't allow me to use subqueries in `CHECK` constraints, which was my first thought. So I tried something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Bar(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  foo INT REFERENCES Foo(id),
  CHECK (3 >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bar B WHERE B.foo = foo))
);
```

This gave me an error saying that I can't use subqueries in check constraints. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You can use a trigger.

Comment: Thanks! I just looked it up. I had not heard of a trigger. I can figure it out from here.

Comment: It allows you to do some actions after/before insert, update, delete. basically

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtrigger.html